# How to speed up dilating a 3D region in a boolean numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-image

I have a 3D numpy array boolean mask which has been segmented from a MRI brain volume.
Brain voxels = True. Everything else = False.

What I would like to do is to enlarge this mask such that it would encompass the surrounding tissues in the MRI volume, not just the segmented organ, perhaps a 10mm rind of non-brain all around the brain.

I tried using a 2D dilation using the skimage.morphology.dilation with a diamond filter.  While this is nice and fast for a single image, I need to repeat this in multiple slices through the volume and in at least 2 planes to come even close to uniformly dilating the 3D mask.

I largely took my code from here: https://scipy-lectures.org/packages/scikit-image/index.html

typical volume shape = 512, 512, 270

```
# 1st pass in axial plane
(x, y, z) = np.shape(3dMask)
for slice_number in range(z):
    image_slice = 3dMask[:, :, slice_number]
    3dMask[:, :, slice_number] = morphology.binary_dilation(image_slice, morphology.diamond(30))
# repeat in coronal plane...
```

This works very nicely with the desired effect in each slice, but is very slow for 3D.
I can speed things up by only dilating those slices containing at least one 'True', but that inevitably leaves 100+ slices in each plane. Still slow.

In the hope that the python side looping is slowing everything down, I have looked for a 3D equivalent single function in numpy and skimage but have found nothing that I can recognise as useful.

I toyed with the idea of finding the geometric centre and simply zooming the volume by 5%, but there will necessarily be holes in the mask (the space in-between the 2 halves of the brain) which will no longer match up with the MRI volume and so is of no use...

I assume this means that I am doing it wrong as I am new to both numpy and skimage.

Is there a fast way to do this? Perhaps a 3D alternative to the 2D skimage dilation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This question actually has a bit of subtlety, which I'll try to unpack.

The first thing to note is that most scikit-image functions actually work totally fine in 3D, including `binary_dilation`! So you *should* in an ideal world be able to do:

```py
dilated = morphology.binary_dilation(
    mask3d, morphology.ball(radius=30)
)
```

I say in an ideal world because that crashes on my machine, probably because [this longstanding SciPy bug](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/4878) prevents SciPy filters (which scikit-image uses under the hood) from working with large neighbourhood sizes.

For square- and diamond-shaped neighbourhoods, though, you do have a workaround: dilating once with a diamond of radius 30 is actually the same as dilating 30 times with a diamond of radius 1! You can do this manually in a for-loop, or you can use `scipy.ndimage.binary_dilation` using the `iterations` keyword argument. (See [this issue](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/issues/954) for some discussion around this.)

```py
from scipy import ndimage as ndi

# make a little 3D diamond:
diamond = ndi.generate_binary_structure(rank=3, connectivity=1)
# dilate 30x with it
dilated = ndi.binary_dilation(mask3d, diamond, iterations=30)
```

You can actually get pretty far with this strategy. For example, if your dataset doesn't have the same resolution in x, y, and z, maybe you want to dilate more, say twice as much, along x and y. You can do this in two steps:

```py
dilated1 = ndi.binary_dilation(mask3d, diamond, iterations=15)
flat = np.copy(diamond)
flat[:, :, 0] = 0
flat[:, :, -1] = 0
dilated2 = ndi.binary_dilation(mask3d, flat, iterations=15)
```

Finally, note that binary dilation is equivalent to a (nonbinary) convolution followed by thresholding above 0. So I found that this also works:

```
from scipy import signal

b = morphology.ball(radius=30)
dilated = signal.fftconvolve(mask3d, b, mode='same') > 0
```

However, for this image size and on my machine, this was slower than the iterated dilation. But, it's worth keeping in mind because the performance will be different for different datasets.

As a side note, I recommend posting complete, working code in your StackOverflow questions, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). In your case, `np.shape(3dMask)` is a syntax error since `3dMask` is not a valid Python identifier! =)

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! I used binary_dilation on the volume - it worked very nicely thank you!
I still had performance issues but much improved.  These were mitigated by reducing the array size by 4 in each axis, dilating then expanding back to original size. This also reduced the neighbourhood size by 4.